# Potential Energy Graph for Nuclear Force

Tags: forces, nuclear-physics, potential-energy, equilibrium

when you draw PE energy graph wrt to distance between two interacting nucleons, at distance $r$ around 1 fm, graph has the lowest PE and is point of stable equilibrum. For $r >$ around 1fm, nuclear force is attractive and  $r<$ around 1fm force is replusive.

I want to know what does it mean when we say at around 1 fm we have point of stable equilibrum? Does it mean that there is no force? if there is no force how come it has the highest -ve energy at that point?

Comment: It means the repulsive and attractive forces are equal, yes the forces add to zero (they are vectors). Do not confuse energy with force.